Two 40uF to equal 80uF capacitor for AC unit
BACKGROUND: I bought a place that has an older Armstrong Concept 1200; I know nothing about it other than the fact that the unit ran fine last year; winter came, and I disconnected the power for safety reasons at the breaker. Fast forward to today, the outside condenser unit isn't powering on and I checked and verified power is getting to the unit.
Upon opening the AC unit, it has TWO 40uF capacitors: Relay to Cap1 Com (Capicitor 1), Cap1 Com jumped to Com Cap2, HERM Cap1 Jumped to HERM Cap2, Cap1 has Fan.
What led me here: Written on the metal next to the Caps is a Note: 80uF/5uF, so I am wondering if the former company didn't happen to have a 80/5 and simply connected two 40/5 for the compressor to equal the 80. The fan of course would be using the 5, thus it's not jumped.
Question: Can I replace both Caps with a single dual 80/5 Cap?
Thank you in advance, and I do greatly appreciate your input and knowledge!

A picture would be helpful to confirm, but yes, two capacitors in parallel add simply, so if two 40's are in parallel they are equivalent to an 80, and an 80/5 should work if that's what's called for, while the pair of 40/5 with one 5 not used would be equivalent if correctly wired up for that.

Thank you! I have a video, but after further investigation, I went with a single 80/5 Cap. This eliminates the guesswork in the future if a single Cap was to go out, and pricewise, it was more affordable, so I bought two of them.
